# Why do I get a complex number using acos?

Tags: matlab, trigonometry, angle, floating-accuracy

For example, if I use the following code to calculate the angle between two vectors `x` and `p`:

```
x = [1 1 -1];
p = [-1 -1 1];

angle = acos(dot(x,p) / (norm(x) * norm(p)));
```

it shows that `angle = 3.141592653589793 - 0.000000021073424i`, which is a complex number.

But we all know that the dot product of `x` and `p` is -3, and the product of the norms of `x` and `p` is 3, so `angle = acos(-3/3)`, so angle should be exactly pi, 3.14159. Why does MatLab give a complex number, and how do I make the result a real number instead?

Comment: I' not near MATLAB, but can you check that the intermediate value is actually -1 not something very close but outside [-1,1] range due to floating point errors?

Comment: here is a relevant page: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101590-how-can-i-determine-the-angle-between-two-vectors-in-matlab (particularly see the comparison between `acos` and `atan2` accuracy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem starts with the normalisation:

```
norm(x) * norm(p)
```

Here you get a value which is slightly off the `3` which you would expect:

```
> (norm(x) * norm(p))-3
ans =   -4.4409e-16
```

The error is propagated and you end up with a acos(x) where x is slighly above 1.

`sqrt` is an operation which potentially causes irational results. When solving it with pen and paper, you would keep the square root and do the multiplication first. Rewrite it that way for better numerical probabillities:

```
angle = acos(dot(x,p) / sqrt(sum(x.^2)*sum(p.^2)))
```

Comment: Thank you, that is a brilliant solution!

Comment: This answer is a bad advice. In either case, you have several floating-point errors, so that in general, there is no guarantee that the acos argument will be in [−1,1] (use min/max to ensure that). The proposed solution works better on the example only because the inputs are very simple, so that `sum(x.^2)*sum(p.^2)` will be computed exactly. On more general examples, this would probably be the opposite because Matlab seems to an accurate algorithm for the `norm` function. But of course, if you know that the elements of your vectors are ±1, the proposed solution is the right one.